# Why I have to put Controller name twice in URL to see the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm make application in .net Core MVC. 
The MapRoute code in startup.cs is like this

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute(name: "AreaRoute",
      template: "{area:required}/{controller:required}/{action}/{id?}",
      defaults: new { area = "Dashboard", controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute(name: "adminRoute",
      template: "{area:required}/{controller:required}/{action}/{id?}",
      defaults: new { area = "Account", controller = "Account" });
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "ControllerRoute",
      template: "{controller:required}/{action}/{id?}",
      defaults: new { area = "Dashboard", controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" });
  });
```

I created areas for each section of my application like this.

[image]

**My Question is** why i need to mention controller name twice in URL to see the view like this

```
http://localhost:54656/Account/account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
```

Comment: Because the controllers are within areas. Let's assume you could write `Account/Login?ReturnUrl=`. Now what happens when you create a controller named `Login` under your `Account` area?

Comment: If I made a Login Controller with index action under Account area I still see the HTTP ERROR 404

If I add the account in url than I can see the login page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you including routes where the area is required, if you don't need the areas and just want to reference your api via Controller/Action/Id

then just use this

```
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

or alternatively remove your the referenced area since its unneeded

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    //Add other routes if needed
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "ControllerRoute",
       template: "{controller:required}/{action}/{id?}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" });
});
```

Comment: this helps me solve my problem. I removed the  {area:required}/  from my template and it's working